# When to use String and string?

Tags: c#

In C#, I've seen that some people use lower case string and sometimes String with Uppercase S. Is there any difference in using them?

```
 string type = "Small";

 String type  = "Large";
```

Comment: @Yulav 21 seconds, not bad.. :)

Comment: @SonerGönül My duplicate question crystal ball alarmed me, it's all thanks to him ;P